# Wordpress: Display Total Number of Posts For Current Month, Week and Day?

Tags: wordpress

I found a way to display the total number of posts made but I need to be able to display the total amount of posts for the current.

Day
Week
Month

Anyone got some code please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can specify time parameters to the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query) function.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Time_Parameters

Comment: I was hoping for more code. I am pretty clueless when it comes to PHP. I can do very little.